# Can PyMacs be used to display graphics in an Emacs window?

Tags: python, emacs, pymacs

[Pymacs](https://github.com/dgentry/Pymacs) ([Documentation](http://web.archive.org/web/20111108014228/http://pymacs.progiciels-bpi.ca/pppp.pdf)) allows you to write plugins for Emacs in Python.

Is it possible to write an Emacs plugin in PyMacs which displays graphics in an Emacs window (using one of the graphics libraries available for Python)?

**Update 1:** Here is the result of the minimal example:

[image: Minimal graphics example]

In the upper right Emacs window, an ellipse, a rectangle and/or a line is displayed by code written, primarily, in Python.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Is there a specific problem that you cannot solve?

Comment: @mzjn I have zero experience with Lisp. So far I could not find any PyMacs code samples that do anything with graphics. Before I invest resources into this, I want to make sure that it is possible in principle. If you know a minimal example of graphics with PyMacs, please provide a link.

Comment: It is hard to help without an actual problem statement or a more detailed specification of the wanted functionality. What do you expect "a minimal example of graphics" to do?

Comment: @mzjn Re *What do you expect "a minimal example of graphics" to do?*: See update 1. I want a piece of code written in Python (primarily) that displays a line, a rectangle, and/or an ellipse in an Emacs window. Any of the three figures would demonstrate that doing graphics in PyMacs is possible in principle. That's what I want.

Comment: @mzjn Also, if you know for sure that graphics is not supported by PyMacs, please tell. The answer "You cannot do graphics in PyMacs" is perfectly acceptable.